# broadcasting a function on a 2-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I would like to improve the speed of my code by computing a function once on a **numpy** array instead of a **for loop** is over a function of [this](https://github.com/GalSim-developers/GalSim) python library. If I have a function as following:

```
import numpy as np
import galsim
from math import *
M200=1e14
conc=6.9
def func(M200, conc):
    halo_z=0.2
    halo_pos =[1200., 3769.7]
    halo_pos = galsim.PositionD(x=halo_pos_arcsec[0],y=halo_pos_arcsec[1])
    nfw      = galsim.NFWHalo(mass=M200, conc=conc, redshift=halo_z,halo_pos=halo_pos, omega_m = 0.3, omega_lam =0.7)
    for i in range(len(shear_z)):
       shear_pos=galsim.PositionD(x=pos_arcsec[i,0],y=pos_arcsec[i,1])
       model_g1, model_g2  = nfw.getShear(pos=self.shear_pos, z_s=shear_z[i])
    l=np.sum(model_g1-model_g2)/sqrt(np.pi)
    return l
```

While `pos_arcsec` is a two-dimensional array of `24000x2` and `shear_z` is a 1D array with `24000` elements as well. 
The **main problem** is that I want to calculate this function on a grid where `M200=np.arange(13., 16., 0.01)` and `conc = np.arange(3,   10, 0.01)`. I don't know how to broadcast this function to be estimated for this two dimensional array over `M200` and `conc`. It takes a lot to run the code. I am looking for the best approaches to speed up these calculations.

Comment: What do you mean by 'broadcast this function'?

Comment: How would it look like with a for loop? I assume 0 and 1 are the variable ones.

Comment: What's the for-loop iterating through? Share the for-loop code?

Comment: @Tichodroma I explained why I needed broadcasting in the new update!

Comment: @PascalvKooten that is my original problem!!

Comment: You might want to mention that you were hoping for a similar solution as mentioned in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774726/numpy-evaluate-function-on-a-grid-of-points

Answer (score 2):

This here should work when `pos` is an array of shape `(n,2)`

```
import numpy as np

def f(pos, z):
    r=np.sqrt(pos[...,0]**2+pos[...,1]**2)
    return np.log(r)*(z+1)
```

Example:

```
z = np.arange(10)
pos = np.arange(20).reshape(10,2)

f(pos,z)
# array([  0.        ,   2.56494936,   5.5703581 ,   8.88530251,
#         12.44183436,  16.1944881 ,  20.11171117,  24.17053133,
#         28.35353608,  32.64709419])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.linalg.norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html)

If you have an array:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la

a = np.array([[3, 4], [5, 12], [7, 24]])
```

then you can determine the magnitude of the resulting vector (sqrt(a^2 + b^2)) by

```
b = np.sqrt(la.norm(a, axis=1)

>>> print b
array([  5.,  15.  25.])
```