# Python - Creating colormap with RGB values defined by X,Y position

Tags: python, rgb, surface, colormap, plane

I am solving a problem, that I solved only half-way.
I am working on 2D drawing space with X,Y coordinates. I want to set 4 points on the drawing space, set color to every point and generate colormap.

I was able to generate colormap with 2 points - create vector and get from one point to another. However this method creates in geometrical sense 2D plane/1D line over the points. But If set 4 points, it requires generating surface. So in other words I need to fit surface in the points.

This is how i imagine it:

[image]

This is my code for generating direct change from one X,Y,[RGB] to another X,Y,[RGB].

```
import numpy as np 
import colorsys
import cv2

a = np.array([100,0,0]) # Point one with x=0,y=0-max and rgb value
b =  np.array([0,255,0]) # point two with x=max,y=0-max and rgb value
#in this case i loop from y=0 to y=max for corresponding point on the other side of drawing space - that is x=max
a = a[::-1]
b= b[::-1]
leds = 31 # just constant
h_color=100 # height of drawing space
t_lengt = (600/leds)*leds #recalculation of width (because I need integer)
vector = (b-a)*1.0/t_lengt

arr_texture = np.zeros(shape=[h_color, t_lengt, 3], dtype=np.uint8) #drawing space defined by x,y and 3d value

for i in range(t_lengt): # loop for all points in x=0 to x=max (that is y=0 to max)
    for j in range(h_color):

        arr_texture[j][i]=[a[0]+vector[0]*i,a[1]+vector[1]*i,a[2]+vector[2]*i]


cv2.imwrite('color_img.jpg', arr_texture)
cv2.imshow("image", arr_texture);
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

result:

[image]

Also I am quite confused about the method, because the points on drawing space are defined by X,Y coordinates but they carry [R,G,B] values.

So to sum it up, I need to fit 3 to **more** points into creating colormap surface, where the points have X,Y coordinates but carry [R,G,B] values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried? From code perspective?

Comment: There's no [tag:python] in this question.

Comment: I havent tried anything yet except doing color map between 2 x,y points with RGB value (but thats not something i need). I cant code it, because I dont even know how to do it. If I had x,y,z values, i can do it, but I have no idea if z dimension contains 3D value in form of RGB. But Ok, I will add a code of what I have but what I dont need

Comment: you do 3 times the same ... interpolate R, than G, than B (separately) and put the results to single color ... it is 3x bilinear interpolation  so 3*3 linear interpolations.... see the links I linked in your other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the RGB values at each of the four corners, so, to be able to create a colormap, all you need is a function that will take a coordinate `(x,y)` (where `x` and `y` are in the range `0` to `1`) and return the RGB value at that coordinate.

To do this, we need to implement [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) which is an extension of interpolating linearly to interpolating in 2d.

---

You  perform bilinear interpolation by interpolating between the top two corners and then interpolating the result of this with the result of the interpolation between the bottom two corners.

```
a ----|---- b
      |
      |
c ----|-----d
```

So before we write our main function, we first need a helper to perform the interpolation as we will be using it nine times.

This could be linear:

```
def lerp(x, a, b):
    return a + x * (b-a)
```

<strike>or something more smooth, like the [smoothstep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep) function:</strike>

```
def serp(x, a, b):
    return a + (3*x**2 - 2*x**3) * (b-a)
```

*(it turns out that for this case where we are just going to the corners (and not hills like with a perlin noise generator), linear produces a more gradual gradient!)*

---

The function will take the four RGB values as four lists/numpy arrays of length `3` (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) and the coordinate (`x`, `y`) to return the RGB value at that coordinate.

```
def get_color(x, y, a, b, c, d):
    r = lerp(y, lerp(x, a[0], b[0]), lerp(x, c[0], d[0]))
    g = lerp(y, lerp(x, a[1], b[1]), lerp(x, c[1], d[1]))
    b = lerp(y, lerp(x, a[2], b[2]), lerp(x, c[2], d[2]))
    return np.array([r, g, b])
```

or, we could make it more Pythonic with a list-comp:

```
def get_color(x, y, a, b, c, d):
    return np.array([lerp(y, lerp(x, a[i], b[i]),
                             lerp(x, c[i], d[i])) for i in range(3)])
```

---

Now we just need to evaluate this over a numpy array which we can use [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) for (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774726/numpy-evaluate-function-on-a-grid-of-points) for alternative methods).

Oh, and I will plot with `matplotlib` as I don't have `OpenCV` installed!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
w = h = 200
verts = [[255,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,0,255],[255,0,0]]
img = np.empty((h,w,3), np.uint8)
for y in range(h):
    for x in range(w):
        img[y,x] = get_color(x/w, y/h, *verts)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

which gives the following image:

[image: colormap.jpg]

---

*This technique is also used in [perlin noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) which allowed me to create this [terrain generator](https://joeiddon.github.io/zengine/demos/terrain.html).*

Comment: Thanks, I already figured this out. But its not very useful when you introduce 5 or more colors. Bilinear interpolation is quite short for this. I tried multiple colors with b. inter., but the result is terrible. I even tried triangulation where triangle edges are THE edges for bilinear inter. but the result is ugly. Also doing b. interpolation inside the triangle doesnt give smooth result. I believe the REAL solution is kind of algorithm, similar to Kohen Maps where there is a fight of influence between each color - that is - kind of classification.

Comment: @Martin Can you add an example of this expected result with 5 colours please.